# Golang mgo json string name consistency

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Let's say we have a Go struct like so

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name" bson:"name"`
}
```

Whenever I want to search a field for this person, in the Mongo module `mgo`, I do something like `userCollection.Find(bson.M{"name" : "John"})`

What I want to know is, is there a way to call `Find` like above, but where I don't need to type out the string field that I'm looking for (`"name"` in this case). I want to avoid this because if I change the `bson` field name in the struct, I'll have to comb through the code base and change it everywhere.

Aside from having global constants everywhere for every struct's field, is there a way to call `mgo` using the struct's own field?

For instance, something which can be called `userCollection.Find(bson.M{Person.Name : "John"})`, which will automatically find `Person.Name` field in the struct (which is `"name"` in this case) and perform the query.

Comment: Isn't it the "default" case to simply use the struct's field name and the  bson:json representation is an override? Pretty sure it is. At any rate, you seem to be missing the difference betwen your struct and the storage. Whilst the details are there to "marshal" a BSON document into your struct, there is not a "query mechanism"  to "construct" a query based on your struct. Not by directlt using `.Find()` anyway. If you feel so inclined to write such a library then by all means go ahead. The .NET driver has functions like this, but generally most lower level drivers do not.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mean the `.Find` method specifically, just if there's a tool I'm missing which finds the struct's current `bson:json` name and uses that for the query. You're right, it is an override to rename it, I'm sticking to a convention with project partner to keep json variables snake case for when it's marshalled.

Comment: See but there's the thing. The `mgo` driver does not do that. And if you are then actually asking for a recommendation on a tool or library, then that's off-topic here. So the driver only understand the bson document you explicitly give it as far as any "query" or "update" or whater. So just BSON only. Your project requirements are of course your own, so it's your choice here that is creating a mismatch. But you still need to create the BSON since the "struct" is not the query. You want a LINQ for Go. But here is not the place to ask.

Comment: Wasn't asking for a recommendation, just if there's something I was missing in the Go standard library, or `mgo` itself. Thanks for the advice, if you turn your response into an answer, I'll mark it as chosen.

Comment: My 2 cents on this: of course, nobody stops you from adding a service layer which does what you describe. If you feel adventurous, make it generic and publish it.